# user.find(1) results in an exception, is my system ok or my setup is messed up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My database is empty, and I understand that I should get an exception.

Just want to make sure that my macbookpro is setup with rails properly.

typing:

user.find(1)

in console I get:

```
>> user.find(1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for #<User:0x1016403a0>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):25
>>
```

I am using rails 3.0, with ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 8):

According to the message `user` is an instance of the `User` class. Since there is no instance method `find` for AR objects (unless you defined it yourself), it's perfectly normal that you get a NoMethodError.

You probably intended to call `User.find(1)` (capital `U`).